# Close window after file is downloaded in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC project where a user can fill the form and click on "Submit" button which returns a File from the controler which they can download:

```
MemoryStream reportCreated = report;
return File(reportCreated, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);
```

How do I close the page after the file is downloaded or download has started?

I have tried...

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
               window.close();
            });
```

and

```
        $('#my-form').submit(function () {
          window.close();
        });
```

...however these closes the page just after the button is clicked or form is submitted.

Comment: You should use an Ajax request after clicking the button and when you got the `success`you close the page

Comment: I have tried ajax however, what should I return from the controller? Returning File(...) doesn't run the `success` section

Comment: Return only the string with the file url/path, in the success redirect the user to the file `window.location.href = 'uploads/file.xls';` so the download start and then close the page.

Comment: File is not created on a physical location. It's a `MemoryStream`.

Answer (score 0):

First use the function `ClosePopupWindow()` where you want the action to be performed.

Foreg.

```
<a onclick="ClosePopupWindow()">close</a>
```

You can use any of these conditons :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ClosePopupWindow() {
        location.href = //You can define the Url where you want to redirect after that. ;
    }

    function ClosePopupWindow() {
        $("divid").remove();//IN case u have any Div then you can put that div id here
    }

    function ClosePopupWindow() {
        $(".divclass").remove();//IN case u have any Div then you can put that div class here
    }
</script>
```

May this will help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: There is no url link, I'm just returning the file so save as dailog will appear directly.